# When someone's hat /etc. blocks your way in a way that you cannot watch something e.g. a movie at a cinema

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, phrases

Imagine a couple who are watching a movie at the theater and in the middle of the film man starts to move his head right and left. Wife asks him: "What's wrong?!" Why are you moving your head that way?"

The husband answers:

> - I can’t see the movie because that woman’s hat **is in the way**.
> - I can’t see the movie because that woman’s hat **has blocked my way**.

Which one of the above-mentioned sentences sounds natural to you? If no one works properly, then please let me know how would a native speaker say it?

Comment: The first one. The second one, I'd say, "because it's blocking me" or "because it's blocking my view."

Comment: Your second sentence, “blocked my way”, would be used when something is preventing you from moving forwards yourself, and not where the object was simply blocking your view. For example: “ I can’t move my car out of my driveway because another car is parked across the entrance, blocking my way”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bothe of your sentences are understandable and correct.

> that woman's hat is in the way.

might also be expressed as

> that woman's hat is in *my* way.

this could also be said if the hat was on the floor blocking the path of the speaker.

> that woman's hat is blocking my view.

is unambiguous and what a native would also say to explain the problem.